# let A be a set of 6 distinct postive integers each <= 12, show that the sum of non empty subests of A cannot all be distinct

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, relations

let A be a set of 6 distinct postive integers each <= 12, show that the sum of non empty subsets of A cannot all be distinct.

for when does this not continue to hold up ( ie instead of 12 , its 13,....)

Comment: So, you mean there exist subsets $E$ and $F$ of $A$ such that $\sum_{x \in E} x =\sum_{y \in F} y$, where the integers $x, y$ are between $1$ and $12$, and $|A| = 6$?

Comment: @gnometorule Ah yes, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As $|A| = 6$, $|\mathcal P(A)| = 2^6 = 64$, so there are at most 64 distinct sums.

Now, note that $12 + 11 + 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 = 57$, and so no subset of $A$ can sum to more than $57$, by distinctness of the elements of $A$. Further, as each element of $A$ is positive, no subset of $A$ can sum to less than $0$.

Therefore, the possible sums for subsets of $A$ are the integers between $0$ and $57$, inclusive. There are precisely 58 of these, and as $58 < 64$, by the pigeonhole principle, some sum must be reached by at least two subsets.

(If we instead consider numbers $\le 13$, then this argument breaks down. $13 + 12 + 11 + 10 + 9 + 8 = 63$, which gives that there are exactly 64 possible sums.)

Comment: How will argument be modified when we have 15 instead of 12

Answer (score 2):

There are $2^6=64$ possible subsets of $A$, the sums of all of them is less than
$12+11+10+9+8+7=57$. There is not enough room for the sums to be all distinct.

Answer (score 0):

put $n$ instead of 12.

the sum of the integers is bounded by $6n-15$, whilst there are $2^6-1$ non-empty subsets